How to set a dynamic range by fixed number
I am trying to set a range by a fixed number for an example.
$fixed = 5;
$value = 7;

So if my value is 7 it will be in a range from 5 to 10
I was trying the old fashion method to add + 5 to the value, but it goes out of the range. (7 + 5 = 12) and it has to be in range between 5 to 10.
$value = 19; // range in 15 to 20
$value = 23; // range in 20 to 25

Any idea?

I think you can also try 5 * intval($fixed / 5) and 5 * (intval($fixed / 5) + 1)

If $value is 5, should the range be [0, 5] or [5, 10]?

This one works, but if the number is 5 it goes to 10 the second range not the first, but anyway this what I am looking for thank you.

@VanshPatel, consider a case when the division approach rounds up the quotient to a whole number value.

This is how you can get such ranges:
function getRange(int $value, int $moduloClass = 5) {
    $start = $value - ($value % $moduloClass);
    $end = $start + $moduloClass;
    return [
        'start' => $start,
        'end' => $end
    ];
}

Explanation:

since you may need this multiple times, we avoid duplicating the same pattern in the code and create a function (or a method) instead
we want to find the range of the $value passed to this function
you want ranges of $moduloClass, so $value will be equal to the greatest number divisible with $moduloClass. The reason why I made this a parameter is to allow you to choose other range sizes too if needed
yet, the default for $moduloClass is 5, so if you do not pass a value for this parameter, it will be assumed to be 5
We compute the remainder of the division of $value to $moduloClass and subtract the result from $value. If $value is 7 and $moduloClass is 5, then $value % $moduloClass is 2 and $value - 2 is 7 - 2 = 5, so this will be assigned to $start
$end will equal to $start + $moduloClass, so if $start was 5, then $end will be 10
we return an array, whose start key will be the start of the range and end key will be the end of the range

Example1
$range = getRange(7); //$moduloClass is defaulting to 5
echo "[" . $range['start'] . ", " . $range['end'] . "]";
//result will be [5, 10]

Example2
$range = getRange(345, 100);
echo "[" . $range['start'] . ", " . $range['end'] . "]";
//result will be [300, 400]


Is there any idea to avoid repeating the range value [0,5] [5,10] to [0,5] [6,10] ?

@Mostafa if you've meant [0,4], [6,9], then it's [$value % $moduloClass, $value % $moduloClass + $moduloClass - 1]. If you've meant something else, then please explain why is your range having 6 elements whereas your second range is having 5 elements, as I would need a clarification for that in order to provide a solution.

It works correctly. Thank you Lajos. I also thank Der Alex , Mustafa and Olivier. all the answers was tested and works as I expect.

Divide the number by 5 and get the integer part. For example 7/5=1.4. Then multiply it by the integer part by 5 1x5=5. Then add 5 and you will see that it is in the range of 5-10. 19/5=3.8 3x5=15 15+5=20 In the range of 15-20. You can do this for other ranges as well.

You can use the floor() function to find the previous or next numbers you need. With floor($value / $fixed) you get a number smaller or greater than $fixed (except you use a multiple of $fixed). This number x $fixed then is your previous number. When you add $fixed to that number, you have the greater number.
$fixed = 5;
$value = 7;

$smaller = floor($value / $fixed) * $fixed;
$greater = $smaller + $fixed;


There exist edge cases when this fails, at least with binary64 math.  Random example: $value = 87109624780633520, $fixed = 5124095575331384. The quotient, rather than being 16.999999999999998438... is 17.0 as round to nearest went up.  $smaller become 87109624780633536, which is larger than $fixed and function returns the wrong range.  Although these numbers are large I suspect a smaller value failure is possible.
